# Mobile Ad Service: Choosing specific ads

Tags: android, ios, mobile, service, ads

I have created a popular mobile app. It is only useful in the local area. Therefore I would like to get custom ads from local businesses in an attempt to get more $$ per click rather than just showing any ad.

I was wondering if there are any mobile ad services that would allow this?

If not, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options for in house ads, you can use admob for in-house ads which is going to be the easiest for android and iAD workbench for iOS.
Pair that with LARSAdController for iOS and you can show inhouse ads.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you [Adsnative](http://adsnative.com/). You can create custom campaing for your local business.